# Multiple Queries and Closing Connections

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to update a column in a few different tables with a very specific value (there are no parameters).

The code is something along the lines of:

```
 public Function InitializeJob()
   {      
     $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("Update `Table1` set `Job` = 'Init');
     $stmt->execute();      
     $stmt->close();

     $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("Update `Table2` set `Job` = 'Init');
     $stmt->execute();      
     $stmt->close();

     $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("Update `Table2` set `Job` = 'Init');
     $stmt->execute();      
     $stmt->close();
   }
```

I was wondering - should I close each connection like that, only to reopen it? Or should I just close it once at the end? $this->mysqli is simply a local variable in my repository that is a mysqli object.

What's the difference from a connection perspective from closing it 3 times, vs. closing it at the end? $this->mysqli will have a value so it's not like i'm reinitializing it (i'm only initializing it if it's null).

My guess is that it's better to only use one $stmt->close() at the very end?

Thanks, was just curious!

Comment: It will take longer to close and reopen it so you shouldn't. You might want to look into some database connection managers (I don't use PHP so don't know any by name) which would take care of it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering - should I close each connection like that, only to reopen it?

No.

> Or should I just close it once at the end?

Neither.

Note that there is no connection to close. What you're closing is a statement, which will be closed on the next line anyway.

> there are no parameters

Then prepared statement is useless here. So your code basically should look like

```
 public Function InitializeJob()
 {      
     $this->mysqli->query("Update `Table1` set `Job` = 'Init'");
     $this->mysqli->query("Update `Table2` set `Job` = 'Init'");
     $this->mysqli->query("Update `Table3` set `Job` = 'Init'");
 }
```

The simpler - the better.

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate this. Could I ask you for some more common sense (lol @ your name) - people always fuss and say how the world will end if you don't close your connections. Then I read all the time elsewhere that PHP automatically closes everything and you don't have to worry about that. If i'm using MYSQLI with or without prepared statements / parameters, do I need to ever worry about closing connections? Isn't it all closed once the script ends anyway?

Comment: No, you shouldn't worry. Besides, there is not a single connection to close in your example. A statement and a connection are the different things.

Answer (score 0):

I think should be done this way

```
 public Function InitializeJob(){     

 $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("mysql statement 1");
 $stmt->execute();   
 $stmt->free_result();   
 $stmt->reset();
 $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("mysql statement 2");
 $stmt->execute();      
 $stmt->free_result();   
 $stmt->reset();

 $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("mysql statement 3");
 $stmt->execute(); 
 $stmt->free_result();   
 $stmt->reset();
 $stmt->close();
}
```

you do a free_result and reset before reusing the $stmt.

Comment: what's the purpose of free result and reset, and what's a potential issue by not doing that? Simply curious, thanks!

Comment: when you execute a mysql statement, usually you expect a result(not always). you clear those result using free_result(), so for the next query...you don't get a residue from the previous query.

Comment: It's a pity that such answers exist on Stack Overflow,

Comment: my answer wasn't exactly wrong. its just that I assumed op's sql statements weren't the real statements, usually done for privacy sake.